# what is ret in ret, track_window=cv2.CamShift()

Tags: python, opencv

I have the code:

```py
ret, track_window = cv2.CamShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)
pts = cv2.boxPoints(ret)
pts = np.int0(pts)
img2 = cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (0, 0, 255), 255)
```

How is `ret` able to help draw the shape? Isn't the rectangle returned by `track_window`? The docs say that `camShift` returns the "number of iterations CAMSHIFT took to converge".

Comment: `ret` mean `return value` which in some functions can be `error code`

Comment: `ret` corresponds to what the [C++ function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#gaef2bd39c8356f423124f1fe7c44d54a1) returns -- i.e. the `RotatedRect`. Since the second parameter `window` is an input/output argument, the Python variant of the function returns it as well.